# Print all local variables in delve debugger

Tags: go, debugging, delve

If my dlv debugging session is in a function and I want to list all the local variables of that function, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the `args` and `locals` commands for this.

For example, for this (nonsense) example code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func example(a, b int) (c int) {
  d := a + b
  if true {
    e := d + 123
    c = e + 1
    fmt.Println("time for a breakpoint")
  }
  return c
}

func main() {
  example(2, 3)
}
```

The output, when stopped at the print statement, is as follows:

```
(dlv) args
a = 2
b = 3
c = 129
(dlv) locals
d = 5
e = 128
```

Refer to Delve's [cli/README.md](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/Documentation/cli/README.md) for more details on the available commands.